# Is the Blaze plan of firebase calculated per day or month?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In Firebase pricing for the (Blaze Plan pricing) of the Cloud Firestore service ,they have written 
(Document writes => $0.18/100K)

(Document reads=>$0.06/100K)

So is the aforementioned cost ($0.18/100K) calculated on daily basis or monthly ?

For example :- If the total document writes for a month is '1,000,000', will it cost me $1.8 or $54, for that month ??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is Cloud Vendor price related

Comment: Please reach out to Firebase support for billing related questions.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Firebase pricing plans](https://firebase.google.com/pricing), the Blaze plan is also named "Pay as you go", which means that you'll be charged according to how much resources you use.

> If the total document writes for a month is '1,000,000', will it cost me $1.8 or $54, for that month ?

If the total document writes for a month is '1,000,000' it cost you $1.8, no matter if you did all those writes in a single day or throughout an entire month.

Comment: Thanks,So after I pay $ 1.8 for that month.Is the statistics of writes( 1,000,000 )being zeroed and will start calculate from zero for the next month

Comment: If you perform only `1,000,000` writes and no more than that, that will be your cost. Yes, it willl start again. If you'll have the next month let's say `500,000`, you'll pay half.

Answer (score 2):

Everyday, you will get a **free quota**:

Firestore:

- writes 20K/day
- reads 50K/day
- deletes 20K/day

then for that day any excess transactions will be billed.
if the total **writes transactions excess** at the end of the month is 1,000,000 then you'll be billed $1.8

The 1,000,000 doesn't include the free daily quotas.

Comment: Thanks,So after I pay $ 1.8 for that month.Is the statistics of writes( 1,000,000 )being zeroed and will start calculate from zero for the next month